# Replacing link text with jQuery doesn't work, no errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's a website that really wants to be bi-lingual even though the CMS doesn't support it. The system buttons can all be in English or Dutch but the content itself not. So they just write articles that have both the English and Dutch text.

Now I know, this is a trainwreck. But this is what the client wants so it's what he gets. I just don't have access to the CMS so I can't do this properly.

Now, to translate the menu buttons I perform a check if the title of a certain element is "Terms of Service" or "Regelement" which tells me if the website is in Dutch or English. I then have an `each` function that runs through all the `li` elements in the menu, checking if the text matches with one of the texts I need to translate, so basically:

```
if ($(this).text() == 'Nieuws') { 
    $(this).text('News'); 
}
```

This used to work, but after recently adding in a language switch button at the top of the website the menu's aren't translated anymore, just the sub menu's. The code runs fine, no errors, and I even put a few alerts in to check if it was detecting the language properly, etc. That all works fine.

For some reason only the submenu's get translated now. The jQuery is of course executed at the end of the page, after the content loads. The website in question is https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/ but you can only see the "Vraag & aanbod" button there.

```js
// for snippet purposes
var setlanguage = 'en';

// If language of user is English
if (setlanguage == 'en') {

 // Loop through each main level menu
 $("#menu li a").each(function(){
  // Set text of menu item to variable
  var tempmenutxt = $(this).text();

  // Translate text of menu item if match is found
  if (tempmenutxt == 'Nieuws ▼') { $(this).text('News ▼'); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'SamenVeilig') { $(this).text("Camera's"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Vraag & aanbod ▼') { $(this).text('Marketplace ▼'); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Informatie ▼') { $(this).text('Information ▼'); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Fotoalbum') { $(this).text("Photo's"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Spelletjes') { $(this).text("Games"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Enquêtes') { $(this).text("Polls"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Koffiehuukske') { $(this).text("Coffeecorner"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Activiteiten') { $(this).text("Activities"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Klachtenhoek') { $(this).text("Complaints"); }
 });
 // Because "display: none;" items can't be read, make all submenu's visible
 $("#menu li ul").each(function(){
  $(this).css("display","block");
 });
 // Translate text of menu item if match is found
 $("#menu li ul li a").each(function(){
  var tempmenutxt = $(this).text();
  if (tempmenutxt == '- Onderhoud aanvragen') { $(this).text('- Request maintenance'); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == '- Goederen/diensten') { $(this).text("- Goods/services"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == '- Mantelzorg / I.B.') { $(this).text("- Caregiving/intensive support"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == '- Belangrijke telefoonnummers') { $(this).text("- Important phone numbers"); }
 });
 // Make all submenu invisible again
 $("#menu li ul").each(function(){
  $(this).css("display","none");
 });
}
```

```css
/* This CSS is just to illustrate, don't mind it, quick and dirty */

#menu {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FF0000;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}

#menu li ul {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1000;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block !important;
}

#menu li ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="/genderhof/">Home</a> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/nieuws" title="Nieuws">Nieuws  ▼</a>       
        
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subMenu3393">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/wooninc" title="- Wooninc.">- Wooninc.</a>
                </li>       
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/CommunityUser/SendGroupMail/740" title="- Onderhoud aanvragen">- Request maintenance</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/samenveilig" title="SamenVeilig">SamenVeilig </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/agenda" title="Agenda">Agenda </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/marktplaats" title="Vraag &amp; aanbod">Vraag &amp; aanbod  ▼</a>       
        
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subMenu3396">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/goederen-diensten" title="- Goederen/diensten">- Goods/services</a>
                </li>       
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/mantelzorg---i-b" title="- Mantelzorg / I.B.">- Caregiving/intensive support</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Informatie">Informatie  ▼</a>       
        
             <ul style="display: none;" id="subMenu3397">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/belangrijke-telefoonnummers_1" title="- Belangrijke telefoonnummers">- Important phone numbers</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/fotoalbum" title="Fotoalbum" tmp_title="Fotoalbum">Fotoalbum </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/chat" title="Chat" tmp_title="Chat">Chat </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/spelletjes" title="Spelletjes">Spelletjes </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/enqu-tes" title="Enquêtes">Enquêtes </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/koffiehuukske" title="Koffiehuukske">Koffiehuukske </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/digisoos" title="Activiteiten">Activiteiten </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/klachtenhoek_1" title="Klachtenhoek">Klachtenhoek </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/digisoos_1" title="Digisoos">Digisoos </a>       
        
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a space problem. In your html they have two spaces `'Nieuws  ▼'`.But compare with javascript single space

```js
// for snippet purposes
var setlanguage = 'en';
$(document).ready(function(){
// If language of user is English
if (setlanguage == 'en') {

 // Loop through each main level menu
 $("#menu li a").each(function(){
  // Set text of menu item to variable
  var tempmenutxt = $(this).text().trim()
  // Translate text of menu item if match is found
  if (tempmenutxt == 'Nieuws  ▼') { $(this).text('News  ▼'); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'SamenVeilig') { $(this).text("Camera's"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Vraag & aanbod  ▼') { $(this).text('Marketplace  ▼'); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Informatie  ▼') { $(this).text('Information  ▼'); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Fotoalbum') { $(this).text("Photo's"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Spelletjes') { $(this).text("Games"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Enquêtes') { $(this).text("Polls"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Koffiehuukske') { $(this).text("Coffeecorner"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Activiteiten') { $(this).text("Activities"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == 'Klachtenhoek') { $(this).text("Complaints"); }
 });
 // Because "display: none;" items can't be read, make all submenu's visible
 $("#menu li ul").each(function(){
  $(this).css("display","block");
 });
 // Translate text of menu item if match is found
 $("#menu li ul li a").each(function(){
  var tempmenutxt = $(this).text().trim();
  if (tempmenutxt == '- Onderhoud aanvragen') { $(this).text('- Request maintenance'); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == '- Goederen/diensten') { $(this).text("- Goods/services"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == '- Mantelzorg / I.B.') { $(this).text("- Caregiving/intensive support"); }
   else if (tempmenutxt == '- Belangrijke telefoonnummers') { $(this).text("- Important phone numbers"); }
 });
 // Make all submenu invisible again
 $("#menu li ul").each(function(){
  $(this).css("display","none");
 });
}
})
```

```css
/* This CSS is just to illustrate, don't mind it, quick and dirty */

#menu {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FF0000;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}

#menu li ul {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1000;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block !important;
}

#menu li ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="/genderhof/">Home</a> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/nieuws" title="Nieuws">Nieuws  ▼</a>       
        
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subMenu3393">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/wooninc" title="- Wooninc.">- Wooninc.</a>
                </li>       
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/CommunityUser/SendGroupMail/740" title="- Onderhoud aanvragen">- Request maintenance</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/samenveilig" title="SamenVeilig">SamenVeilig </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/agenda" title="Agenda">Agenda </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/marktplaats" title="Vraag &amp; aanbod">Vraag &amp; aanbod  ▼</a>       
        
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subMenu3396">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/goederen-diensten" title="- Goederen/diensten">- Goods/services</a>
                </li>       
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/mantelzorg---i-b" title="- Mantelzorg / I.B.">- Caregiving/intensive support</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Informatie">Informatie  ▼</a>       
        
             <ul style="display: none;" id="subMenu3397">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/belangrijke-telefoonnummers_1" title="- Belangrijke telefoonnummers">- Important phone numbers</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/fotoalbum" title="Fotoalbum" tmp_title="Fotoalbum">Fotoalbum </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/chat" title="Chat" tmp_title="Chat">Chat </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/spelletjes" title="Spelletjes">Spelletjes </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/enqu-tes" title="Enquêtes">Enquêtes </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/koffiehuukske" title="Koffiehuukske">Koffiehuukske </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/digisoos" title="Activiteiten">Activiteiten </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/klachtenhoek_1" title="Klachtenhoek">Klachtenhoek </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/digisoos_1" title="Digisoos">Digisoos </a>       
        
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just couldn't find it, but every menu text now has an extra space behind it. Seems like the developers messed something up with yesterday's update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two spaces between the symbol and the name, so I guess the if statements are simply not true

Answer (score 1):

Use his. This snippet is working

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
 $("a").filter(function(index) {
     if($(this).text().includes("Nieuws")) {
          var text = $(this).text()
          $(this).text(text.replace("Nieuws", "News"))
          }
    
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="/genderhof/">Home</a> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/nieuws" title="Nieuws">Nieuws  ▼</a>       
        
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subMenu3393">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/wooninc" title="- Wooninc.">- Wooninc.</a>
                </li>       
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/CommunityUser/SendGroupMail/740" title="- Onderhoud aanvragen">- Request maintenance</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/samenveilig" title="SamenVeilig">SamenVeilig </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/agenda" title="Agenda">Agenda </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/marktplaats" title="Vraag &amp; aanbod">Vraag &amp; aanbod  ▼</a>       
        
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subMenu3396">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/goederen-diensten" title="- Goederen/diensten">- Goods/services</a>
                </li>       
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/mantelzorg---i-b" title="- Mantelzorg / I.B.">- Caregiving/intensive support</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Informatie">Informatie  ▼</a>       
        
             <ul style="display: none;" id="subMenu3397">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/belangrijke-telefoonnummers_1" title="- Belangrijke telefoonnummers">- Important phone numbers</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/fotoalbum" title="Fotoalbum" tmp_title="Fotoalbum">Fotoalbum </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/chat" title="Chat" tmp_title="Chat">Chat </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/spelletjes" title="Spelletjes">Spelletjes </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/enqu-tes" title="Enquêtes">Enquêtes </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/koffiehuukske" title="Koffiehuukske">Koffiehuukske </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/digisoos" title="Activiteiten">Activiteiten </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/klachtenhoek_1" title="Klachtenhoek">Klachtenhoek </a>       
        
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.onsplatform.tv/genderhof/digisoos_1" title="Digisoos">Digisoos </a>       
        
        </li>
    </ul>
  
  
<button class="btn">Change</button>
```